# windows bat file to find a Folder by name and return its path

Tags: windows, batch-file

In windows cmd how can i search for a file by name. Then add the variable to select its full path.
ie find Folder Test1 and return Drive\somewhere\test1

```
@ECHO OFF
dir /s /a-d *Testl* >nul && (echo found it) || (echo not found)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /f "usebackq" %a in (`dir /b /s /a-d ^| findstr "Test1"`) do set fileLocation=%~pa
echo %fileLocation%
```

A potential drawback here is that if it finds `Test1` in multiple folders, `%fileLocation%` will be set with only the last folder it finds.